# RecyclerView in Android Studio repeats an action

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I create an empty app in android studio with java just for showing my problem.
In this program, if I check the first check box, with a distance of 10 items, other check boxes above and below will also be checked (this distance is different in different devices, and as the device becomes more powerful, this distance increases).
This problem is not only related to the checkbox, it happened to several other components that I tried.
I tried `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` and `LinearLayoutManager` on `api` 26 and 32 and still had the problem.
Is there a way to fix this problem? I designed my main application based on recyclerview and now I ran into this problem.

MainActivity JAVA code:

```
package com.coders.rv_test;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RecyclerView rv = findViewById(R.id.rv);
        adapt adapt = new adapt(this);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        rv.setAdapter(adapt);
    }
}
```

activity_main XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">



    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Adapter code:

```
package com.coders.rv_test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class adapt extends RecyclerView.Adapter<adapt.MyViewHolder> {

    Context context;

    public adapt(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.rv_view,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 100;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

Adapter view code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a lot of ways and finally I realized that the main problem is that when the height of the `RecyclerView` increases, problems like this arise. By placing `RecyclerView` in a `NestedScrollView`, this problem was solved for all components in `RecyclerView`. I tried this way in my main app and the problem was solved there too. I put the code below:

```
activity_main XML code:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: you shouldn't not put recyclerview inside nestedscrollview, because that will make recyclerview can't recycle its child view. this goes against the purpose of recyclerview. with 100 items you will hardly notice the change, but when putting in a list with thousands of items, if the view is not recycled it will become laggy and reduce the user experience

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is probably because the recyclerview recycled the views of its items.

With each item (in your case is 100 item), you will need a variable to check the checkbox inside item has clicked or not. if it clicked, you will set checked for checkbox = true, else is false. Something like this:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder == MyViewHolder) {
            holder.bind(position);
        }
    }

    Int clickedPosition = -1;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
        
        public void bind(int position) {
            yourCheckBoxId.setClick {
                clickedPosition = position;
            }
            if (position == clickedPosition) {
                yourCheckBoxId.setChecked = true;
            } else  {
                yourCheckBoxId.setChecked = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Above code just illustration for my answer.
This code just fine when you click one checkbox, if you clickmore, you will need a list clickedPosition, or a object with check field

Answer (score 1):

I have solved your problem by passing the list in an adapter constructor instead of taking the hardcode value in the adapter class as 100.

This list contains the integer value as 0 or 1, if 0 is set then the checkbox is unchecked and if it is 1 then the checkbox is set as checked. You can replace the list object with your model class according to your requirements.

MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RecyclerView rv = findViewById(R.id.rv);
    adapt adapt = new adapt(this, new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(100, 0)));
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    rv.setAdapter(adapt);
}
```

Updated your adapter class as follows:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class adapt extends RecyclerView.Adapter<adapt.MyViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Integer> list;

public adapt(Context context, ArrayList<Integer> integers) {
    this.context = context;
    this.list = integers;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.rv_view, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.box.setChecked(list.get(position) != 0);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    CheckBox box;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        box = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxx);
        box.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                list.set(getAdapterPosition(), list.get(getAdapterPosition()) == 0 ? 1 : 0);
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

Adapter view code as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBoxx"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```